# How to deserialize a parking_lot::Mutex with Serde?

Tags: rust, mutex, serde

I have a struct of memory (`obj`) wrapped in an `Arc<Mutex>`. The `Mutex` is an improved version of the `std::sync::Mutex` in the parking_lot crate. I need to deserialize the wrapped object (`obj`), however, I get an error:

```
the trait `_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_SecurityLevel::_serde::Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `lock_api::mutex::Mutex<parking_lot::raw_mutex::RawMutex, Obj>`
```

In my Cargo.toml, I have (notably):

```
serde = { version = "1.0.89", features = ["rc"] }
parking_lot = {version = "0.8", features = ["nightly"]}
```

How should I go about this? Is there a workaround, or must I manually implement the traits?

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for Serde was added to parking_lot 0.8 under the `serde` [feature flag](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-features-section):

```
parking_lot = { version = "0.8", features = ["nightly", "serde"] }
```

Using this, the code you have provided compiles. This also compiles:

```
use parking_lot::Mutex;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

fn implements<T>()
where
    Mutex<T>: for<'a> Deserialize<'a> + Serialize,
{
}
```